# Javascript: How do I wait until async response has required data before continuing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, asynchronous

How do I wait until the async response has required data before continuing?

I have a few async functions that apply a discount and fetch the order that SHOULD contain the order with a discount applied. The problem is sometimes the discount is applied and order call does not contain the discounts in the response. (I am guessing the process takes a few seconds for the discount to reflect on the order). What is the best way to ensure the required data is present before moving on to the code? I tried below, but no luck. Thanks in advance.

```
             //Apply Discount
             await this.attemptDiscount(
                payload
              );

              const order = await this.ordersService.getOrder(
                orderId
              );

              //Required condition
              if (
                order.hasOwnProperty("discounts") &&
                order.discounts[0].name ===
                  "Exclusive Discount"
              ) {
                // Proceed with code
              }
```

Comment: Since you've left no information about implementation details, all I can think of is, you should check the implementation of `attemptDiscount` and make sure that it fulfills the promise only after the discount is applied.

Comment: Are you saying that the server sometimes returns bad data? It sounds like it's their bug. If you know them, yell at them. If you need a work around, you probably need to recursively call the function until it Returns the result you expect, possibly with a delay

Comment: @AluanHaddad, unfortunately, it is a third party source, I went down the road of using a setInterval. Thanks!

Comment: @user7659932 instead of setInterval, you can write a helper `function delay(ms: number) { return new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, ms))}`. Then you can `await delay(retryAfter)`.

Answer (score -1):

You should call await inside an async function

```
async applyDiscountAndOrderItem(payload,orderId){


 var discount =  await this.attemptDiscount(
                payload
              );

              const order = await this.ordersService.getOrder(
                orderId
              );

              //Required condition
              if (
                order.hasOwnProperty("discounts") &&
                order.discounts[0].name ===
                  "Exclusive Discount"
              ) {
                // Proceed with code
              }
}
```

You can call tis function this

```
applyDiscountAndOrderItem(payload,orderId).then((response)=>{


success call back

},(err)=>{
eror call back
})
```